# Can a German citizen invite me to the Czech Republic while living abroad?

Tags: schengen, germany, netherlands, czech-republic, invitation-letters

A German friend of mine lives in Taiwan. He is on a short trip to the Hague right now. We would like to travel together to the Czech Republic for 14 days.

I have an Iranian passport but living in Turkey. I have previous UK and Schengen visas on my passport.

1. Is it possible for him to send me an invitation letter from the Netherlands?
2. Should he visit a police station in order to do this?

Answer (score 3):

In Germany there is a special kind of invitation called a [Verpflichtungserklärung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verpflichtungserkl%C3%A4rung_(Ausl%C3%A4nderrecht)), where the sponsor guarantees to reimburse the German government for any costs should the visitor overstay. This kind of invitation is **usually not required** to apply for a visa, but it may cause the granting of a visa that would otherwise be denied (because the applicant is deemed a high risk for overstay). This letter must be filed with the municipal authorities, not the police.

But that wouldn't help with the Czech authorities.

Comment: +1 on the notion this wouldn't help at all with the Czech authorities.

Comment: OP can also change his plans and go to Germany instead. Say, 8 days in Germany and 6 days in Czech Republic would be okay.

Comment: @JonathanReez what purpose would that serve? Is there any reason not to plan a 2-week trip to the Czech republic?

Comment: Assuming OP *needs* an invitation he could use that route to get a German visa. It's also possible that the Czech consulate is farther away and less convenient.